# How do i make a canvas as the background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to use a custom canvas as the background image but my page has colapsible created from this [template](https://colorlib.com/wp/template/bootstrap-sidebar-04/)

```
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <nav id="sidebar">
            <h1><a href="#" class="logo">App</a></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home mr-3"></span> home </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      <div id="content" >      
      <div style="position: absolute;">
        <div class="custom-menu" >
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
            </button>
        </div>
<h1> Hello world</h1>
</div>
<canvas width="max-width" height="max-height" id="canv"></canvas>
<script>
  // Initialising the canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canv'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Function to resize the canvas to fill the viewport
  function resizeCanvas() {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  resizeCanvas();

  // Setting up the draw function
  function draw() {/*...*/}
  // Loop the animation
  setInterval(draw, 60);
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

the page renders fine but when the collapse menu is pressed it gets scrolled and I get a space to the right and the bottom of the page that is not covered by the canvas

Comment: Where do you resize and redraw the canvas on a size change?

Answer (score 0):

To write a responsive resize for canvas you must add the following code:

```
window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
```

If you want to use the canvas as an image, you can do so using the toDataURL() method , this method will turn your canvas into an image that you can use in css styles

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        
        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            render();
            document.body.style.background = "url('" + canvas.toDataURL() + "')";
        }

        resizeCanvas();

        window.onresize = resizeCanvas;

        function render() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        render();


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to the body background styles in the code inspector.

To remove scrollbars you can write overflow: hidden property in css styles;